# how to select a value from hover dropdown using selenium ruby capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, drop-down-menu, hover

How to select a value from hover dropdown using selenium ruby capybara?

I have tried using the below code, but it didnt work:

```
page.driver.action.move_to('variable').perform
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code that work for me

`page.driver.browser.action.move_to(page.find('YourElement').native).perform`

Comment: i tried that but i am getting an error unknown command: :mouseMoveTo (ArgumentError) @Engrengr-hasanuzzaman-sumon

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Selenium 3.0+ with firefox 48+ then :mouseMoveTo isn't supported yet (hasn't been implemented by geckodriver/marionette).  You either need to revert to firefox <= 47.0.1 and disable :marionette or swap to a different browser (Chrome for instance) for your testing.